# How to open file using TextMate with new tab

Tags: textmate

Everytime i open a file with text mate and it is by default in new window, is it possible to open in new tab so I don't need to mess with the windows?

I am using latest textmate2 downloaded from github.

Answer (score 8):

I am a novice with Textmate2 but have found when opening a file via the TextMate File Browser it open files in tabs.  Go to View->Show File Browser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using TextMate without the internal project functionality you can set your home directory or / as project folder.

Go to the Project folder (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) drop down the list and choose your home directory. Then drop down again and choose *Use "MyName" as Project Folder*. As @Tony has stated in his answer, all files udner the project dir are opened in tabs by default.

It works for TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9475.

Answer (score 4):

Also a bit of a work around. 
After opening several windows with text mate you can go to the menu bar
Window > Merge All Windows

I also have a keyboard shortcut set up to quickly access the menu bar. This allows me to do this pretty easily and without a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This will afaik only work if you are opening files that are in the same directory. Currently, Textmate 2 couples directories with projects.

A hacky and possibly not very extendable way would be to open a folder higher in the hierarchy every time you open an ad-hoc file in your filesystem like so:

```
mate ~/Sites ~/Sites/my-site/index.html
mate ~/Sites ~/Sites/my-other-site/index.html
```

This will open both files in the same window, since you are telling Textmate that your project is the `~/Sites` directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - if all you're trying to do is just open some files in the same window instead of in different windows, you can just do:

`mate file1 file2`

And put both files in the same window.